Standardization or Normalization for K-means clustering
For context, I have a dataset with 50000 data and need to perform K-means clustering.
Dataset:

I was wondering which scaling I should perform on the dataset before clustering.
This is the question for further context:
Use the following sets of features to perform k-Means clustering with k = 5.
Set 1: GENDER, EDUCATION, AGE, MARRIGAE, CREDIT_LIMIT
Set 2: BALANCE(-2), MIN_PAY(-2), EXPENSE(-2), FAILURE_ATTEMPT(-2), PAY(-2), DEFAULT(-2)
Set 3: BALANCE(-1), MIN_PAY(-1), EXPENSE(-1), FAILURE_ATTEMPT(-1), PAY(-1), DEFAULT(-1)
Set 4: BALANCE(0), MIN_PAY(0), EXPENSE(0), FAILURE_ATTEMPT(0)
i)  Explain any scaling method that you used and justify why.
ii) For each set, determine the number of samples and the proportion of positive cases in each cluster.
iii)    Identify if the clustering results are useful to show any characteristics of the positive cases and justify your answer.
# Define feature sets
feature_sets = {
    "Set 1": ['GENDER', 'EDUCATION', 'AGE', 'MARRIAGE', 'CREDIT_LIMIT'],
    "Set 2": ['BALANCE(-2)', 'MIN_PAY(-2)', 'EXPENSE(-2)', 'FAILURE_ATTEMPT(-2)', 'PAY(-2)', 'DEFAULT(-2)'],
    "Set 3": ['BALANCE(-1)', 'MIN_PAY(-1)', 'EXPENSE(-1)', 'FAILURE_ATTEMPT(-1)', 'PAY(-1)', 'DEFAULT(-1)'],
    "Set 4": ['BALANCE(0)', 'MIN_PAY(0)', 'EXPENSE(0)', 'FAILURE_ATTEMPT(0)']
}

# Initialize the scaler
scaler = StandardScaler()

# Process each feature set
scaled_data = {}
for set_name, features in feature_sets.items():
    if set_name == "Set 1":
        # One-Hot Encode categorical variables for Set 1
        df_encoded = pd.get_dummies(train[features], columns=['GENDER', 'EDUCATION', 'MARRIAGE'])
        # Scale the encoded data
        scaled_data[set_name] = scaler.fit_transform(df_encoded)
    else:
        # Scale the data for other sets
        scaled_data[set_name] = scaler.fit_transform(train[features])

# Perform k-Means clustering
k = 5
cluster_results = {}
for set_name, data in scaled_data.items():
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, random_state=0)
    clusters = kmeans.fit_predict(data)
    cluster_results[set_name] = clusters
    train[f'Cluster_{set_name}'] = clusters

# Determine the number of samples and the proportion of positive cases in each cluster
results_summary = {}
for set_name in feature_sets.keys():
    cluster_col = f'Cluster_{set_name}'
    summary = train.groupby(cluster_col)['DEFAULT(0)'].agg(['count', 'mean'])
    summary['positive_proportion'] = summary['mean']
    summary = summary.drop(columns=['mean'])
    results_summary[set_name] = summary

# Print the results summary for each set
for set_name, summary in results_summary.items():
    print(f"Results for {set_name}:\n{summary}\n")

This is the current code I used for Standardization and I am unsure if its accurate since using Normalization scaling gives vastly different results.

Which language and libraries are you using?

I am using python and the sklearn library

Can you post the code you have already done?

Yep Posted. Code works fine but I just to check which scaling method should I use for the dataset.
